# Функции, параметры и psycopg2

Tags: python, функции, psycopg2

Не могу разобраться с функциями и параметрами(
Подскажите пожалуйста и не кидайте тапками

```
def get_connect_to_database():
    try:
        connect = psycopg2.connect(dbname = name_of_database, user = user, password = password, host= host)
        print('\n', Fore.GREEN+'================= CONNECTION OK =================')
        print(Fore.RESET)
        cur = connect.cursor()
        time_start = time.time()
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(Fore.RED + '[-Error-]CONNECTION NOT OK', _ex)


def get_query_from_database():
    try:
        get_data_from_first_table = """
            SELECT id,pas_id, date_add, status_id
            FROM status_history 
            where status_id !=7
            and date_add>= now()- interval '10 day'
            order by date_add desc limit 50"""
        cur.execute(get_data_from_first_table)
        data_frame_from_first_table = cur.fetchall()
        print(get_data_from_first_table)
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(Fore.RED + "[-Error-] ERROR WITH QUERY")
```

Как мне правильно добавить `cur` в функцию `def get_query_from_database()`. Он не активен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Передавать в параметры:

```
def get_connect_to_database():
    try:
        connect = psycopg2.connect(dbname = name_of_database, user = user, password = password, host= host)
        print('\n', Fore.GREEN+'================= CONNECTION OK =================')
        print(Fore.RESET)
        cur = connect.cursor()
        time_start = time.time()
        return cur # <---
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(Fore.RED + '[-Error-]CONNECTION NOT OK', _ex)

def get_query_from_database(cur): # <---
    try:
        get_data_from_first_table = """
            SELECT id,pas_id, date_add, status_id
            FROM status_history 
            where status_id !=7
            and date_add>= now()- interval '10 day'
            order by date_add desc limit 50"""
        cur.execute(get_data_from_first_table)
        data_frame_from_first_table = cur.fetchall()
        print(get_data_from_first_table)
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(Fore.RED + "[-Error-] ERROR WITH QUERY")

cur = get_connect_to_database() # <---
if cur: # <---
    get_query_from_database(cur) # <---
```

2. Сделать переменную глобальной:

```
cur = None # <---

def get_connect_to_database():
    global cur # <---
    try:
        connect = psycopg2.connect(dbname = name_of_database, user = user, password = password, host= host)
        print('\n', Fore.GREEN+'================= CONNECTION OK =================')
        print(Fore.RESET)
        cur = connect.cursor()
        time_start = time.time()
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(Fore.RED + '[-Error-]CONNECTION NOT OK', _ex)


def get_query_from_database():
    global cur # <---
    try:
        get_data_from_first_table = """
            SELECT id,pas_id, date_add, status_id
            FROM status_history 
            where status_id !=7
            and date_add>= now()- interval '10 day'
            order by date_add desc limit 50"""
        cur.execute(get_data_from_first_table)
        data_frame_from_first_table = cur.fetchall()
        print(get_data_from_first_table)
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(Fore.RED + "[-Error-] ERROR WITH QUERY")
```

Comment: А если мне нужно будет передать полученное `data_frame_from_first_table = cur.fetchall()` из второй функции куда-то еще, например, в другую функцию, то как быть? Вернее как передать?

Comment: @Nommad опять также. `res = get_query_from_database(cur); another_func(res)`

Comment: Спасибо большое)